# Firebase return data to listview

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I tried to follow some tutorials before asking here, but when trying to reproduce according to the tutorial of other people there was a hashmap to string error and things like that.

My doubts are as follows:

The way I'm doing below I can get the values ​​from the Firebase, but I'd like to get only the information inside the "food" (meat, chicken, ..) without the information if it's good or not. And how to list the items instead of putting them all together.
Thank's

[image]

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    DatabaseReference dref;
    ListView listview;
    ArrayList < String > list = new ArrayList < > ();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        final ArrayAdapter < String > adapter = new ArrayAdapter < String > (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

        dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        dref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                String teste = dataSnapshot.child("Restarant").child("foods").getValue().toString();

                adapter.add(teste);
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });



    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly isn't working?  What are you trying, and what is your expected output?  Actual output? Thanks

Comment: I would like to fetch the data within foods, but only (meat, pork, chicken) without the status, it is currently like this: {chicken = good, pork = amazing, meat = good} it shows everyone on the same line. I wish it were:
-pork
-chicken -Meat

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


 DatabaseReference dref;
 ListView listview;
 ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);

   final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);

   dref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Restarant");

   dref.child("foods").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


       list.add(dataSnapshot.child("chicken").getValue(String.class));
       list.add(dataSnapshot.child("meat").getValue(String.class));
       list.add(dataSnapshot.child("pork").getValue(String.class));


        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
}
}
```

Comment: I tried this and doesnt work:
04-17 21:46:04.106 10096-10096/cai.com.fireteste E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: cai.com.fireteste, PID: 10096 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:409) at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)...

Comment: Have you removed the database?

Comment: No,the database remains active and with the same names inside.

Comment: Fixed, little typo on restaurant

Comment: I did a test:
 public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) String value = (dataSnapshot.child("Restarant").getValue(String.class));
                                          list.add(value.toString());
                                           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
and error changes...now is FATAL EXCEPTION: mainProcess: cai.com.fireteste, PID: 14802                                                                   com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.util.HashMap to String

Comment: String value = (dataSnapshot.child("Restarant").getValue(String.class));
list.add(value);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: cai.com.fireteste, PID: 24761
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: Shutting down VM
04-18 14:06:08.820 5566-5566/cai.com.fireteste E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: cai.com.fireteste, PID: 5566
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference